# Spring boot Oauth security - User(custom info) info in the principal in Client Credentials grant type

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2, clientcredential

I'm using "client-credentials" grant type for the rest calls that I make from front-end service to other back-end services. Client-credentials grant type is being used among other back-end services as well. By doing so, I am not able to get who is the actual invoker (currently logged in user) of a request. Is there a way to inject authentication and authorization info of the principal to the token that is being issued in the client-credentials grant? (user info means the id or details of the user who has the client credentials).
I can add some custom data to the token by using a custom token enhancer. But I couldn't find out how we can get it in the principal(`SpringSecurityPrincipal springSecurityPrincipal = (SpringSecurityPrincipal)oAuth2Authentication.getPrincipal();`), normally in the password flow we can achieve this by using custom `AuthenticationProvider` implementation like that is there any class that I can implement and use to add custom principal?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom `UserDetailsService` and create a custom `Principal` according to your requirements. You might pick some ideas from here: [Authentication with a Database-backed UserDetailsService](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-with-a-database)

Comment: That will only work for the password grant type, right? I already have that implementation, the client credentials flow is not passing through that implementation. Since some grant types do not require user authentication(our case -  client credentials )